# Creating dummy variables in R where element in data frame 2 is in data frame 1

Tags: r, loops

I have a main data frame with a column for year of event A occurring. I have two separate data frames with year of events B and year of event C occurring.

Sample dataframe:

```
year_eventA <- c(1995,1996,1997,1998,1999)
year_eventB <- c(1997,1999)
year_eventC <- c(1995)

main_df <-data.frame(year_eventA)
df1 <-data.frame(year_eventB)
df2 <-data.frame(year_eventC)
```

I want to add a column to my main data frame that will specify weather event B occurred and another column that will do the same thing for event C.

For example

| year_eventA | Event B | Event C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1995 | 0 | 1 |
| 1996 | 0 | 0 |
| 1997 | 1 | 0 |
| 1998 | 0 | 0 |
| 1999 | 1 | 0 |

I am not sure how to do this. I thought of using for loops, but I'm just starting to learn R after working with python and am not sure how things would translate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to create these two new variables:

```
EventB <- (year_eventA %in% year_eventB) + 0L
#[1] 0 0 1 0 1

EventC <- (year_eventA %in% year_eventC) + 0L
#[1] 1 0 0 0 0
```